# Euclidean angle vs euclidean distance between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define the euclidean angle between two vectors as
$$
a(x,y) := \arccos\left(\frac{x^\top y}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}\right).
$$
Assuming $\|x\| = \|y\| = \|z\| = 1$ for a general norm $\|\cdot\|$ (i.e., not necessarily the $\ell_2$ norm $\|\cdot\|_2$), I would like to show that
$$
a(x,y) \leq a(x,z) \iff \|x-y\|_2 \leq \|x-z\|_2.
\tag{1}
$$

Geometrically, this makes sense to me. However, I have been trying to prove it using the identity $2x^\top y = \|x\|_2^2 + \|y\|_2^2 - \|x-y\|_2^2$, the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and equivalence of norms, without success.

My questions are:

- Is (1) true?
- If not, does it hold for some special case other than $\|\cdot\| = \|\cdot\|_2$? Perhaps if we define the angle using a general norm as well instead of the $\ell_2$ norm? Or if the inequality on the right hand side of (1) used a general norm as well?

**Edit 1**: fixed typo in the definition of angle.

Comment: The angle is most certainly NOT defined in that way

Comment: also, you're very close to the solution. The first identity you wrote is enough to conclude

Comment: @durdi The angle between two vectors is $\arccos (\frac{x^Ty}{\|x\|\,\|y\|})$. The formula you have written is incorrect

Comment: @BenGrossmann fixed the typo

Comment: @Exodd you mean the identity I wrote is enough, even for the case when we only assume $\|x\| = \|y\| = \|z\| = 1$ for a general norm $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: One trouble is that the expression $x^\top y$ for the inner product of two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ is really tied to the $\ell_2$ norm specifically. And not all norms come from inner products.

Comment: You should look up the metric geometry concept of angles in metric spaces. Essentially, you can define a reasonable notion of angle between geodesics using the law of cosines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: No.

Take the max norm on $\mathbb R^2$, for example. Your conjecture implies that $a(x,y)=a(x,z)\iff\lVert x-y\rVert_2=\lVert x-z\rVert_2$, provided that $\lVert x\rVert_\infty=\lVert y\rVert_\infty=\lVert z\rVert_\infty=1$.

Let $x=(1,1/2)$, $y=(1,0)$, and $z=(1,1)$. Clearly the Euclidean distances are both $1/2$, but the angles are not equal: $\arccos(2/\sqrt5)\neq\arccos(3/\sqrt{10})$.